# Is there a command to start Nemo file manager and search for files?

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, nemo, file-search

Nemo is good at searching for files and folders.

I use Nemo file manager in Xfce and would like to add the Nemo file-search action to WhiskerMenu in the same way Catfish is integrated to Whisker Menu following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/785894/925128):

[image]

Creating links to folders of other partitions in some location in $HOME and searching there would extend the search to those folders too, something that Catfish doesn't do.

I would need a command that would start Nemo (by default in $HOME) and search for a variable file-name.

During search, the CPU is put to work by the `nemo` process;

[image]

but `nemo --help-all` and `man nemo` show no useful options.

Comment: I have found a partial solution, the problem is that it opens each result in a new window. Would you like that I write this as an answer?

Comment: @guillermochamorro - of course you could post that, thank you.

Comment: @guillermochamorro - that could give ideas for other solutions. post your thing as a comment or as an answer - mentioning it is temporary

Answer (score 1):

The best way I could find is to use a script, since "Find commands" doesn't accept some bash commands, like `xargs`:

Create a script with any name, in this case we will call it `search`:

```
#!/bin/bash

find /my/path -name "*$1*" | head -5 | xargs nemo
```

Make the file executable:

```
chmod +x search
```

Then in the "Find commands" insert:

```
/path/to/my/script/search %s
```

> The problem with this approach is that it will open a new browser for each result found! To avoid having dozens of windows opened, you can use a constraint like `head` or `tail`, wich will give a fixed number of results. In the example above, only 5 windows will be opened.

Comment: Replace `xargs nemo` with `xargs nemo --existing-window` and it will open the results in new tabs in the same window.